Drop down menu not functioning properly
I'm working on the reponsiveness of my site using media queries. when i click on the icon, the menu drops but when i click agaiin to return... it doesn't return.
my html code
<nav>
  <img src="../images/shotbyopi.logo (5).png" alt="logoPic" />
  <ul id="sidemenu">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <hr />
    <li><a href="#about-1">About</a></li>
    <hr />
    <li><a href="#wrapper">Services</a></li>
    <hr />
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <i class="fa-solid fa-circle-chevron-down" onclick="toggleMenu()"></i>
</nav>

This is my css for the specific screens i'm working on
@media (min-width: 481px) and (max-width: 768px) {
  nav .fa-circle-chevron-down {
    display: block;
    font-size: 85px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 4px #fff;
    z-index: -2;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    margin-top: 60px;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  nav img {
    width: 325px;
    height: 325px;
  }

  nav .fa-solid:hover {
    transform: translateY(-10px);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
  }

  nav ul {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    row-gap: 20px;
    margin-left: 0;
    background: transparent;
    position: fixed;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    top: -100vh;
    left: 0;
    width: 27%;
    height: 100vh;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    z-index: 2;
    transform: translateX(230%);
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
  }

  /* When the menu is active */
  nav ul.show-menu {
    top: 0; /* Slide down into view */
  }

  /* Styling for individual list items */
  nav ul li {
    margin: 5px 0;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
  }

  /* Make sure links are styled clearly */
  nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}

The provided CSS code seems to be styling a navigation element (nav) with a menu icon and a list of items.
my javascript code for the functionality of the menu bar

function toggleMenu() {
    const menu = document.getElementById('sidemenu');
    const toggleIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');
  
    menu.classList.toggle('show-menu');
    toggleIcon.classList.toggle('rotate');
  }
  
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const toggleIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');
  
    if (toggleIcon) {
      toggleIcon.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
    } else {
      console.error('Element with class "toggle-menu" not found.');
    }
  });

I tried to get a correction from Gemini AI, but it began to show me errors, below is the javascript code
function toggleMenu() {
  const menu = document.getElementById('sidemenu');
  const toggleIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');

  menu.classList.toggle('show-menu');
  toggleIcon.classList.toggle('rotate');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const toggleIcon = document.querySelector('.toggle-menu');

  if (toggleIcon) {
    toggleIcon.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
  } else {
    console.error('Element with class "toggle-menu" not found.');
  }
});


Probably the defined toggleIcon constant is not what you expect. There's no element with the class toggle-menu in your HTML.

You said there were errors?

Consider adding an express check whether the menu has been opened, and hiding if the menu is already visible, instead of the toggle function.
function toggleMenu()
{
  const menu = document.getElementById('sidemenu');  
  const toggleIcon = document.querySelector ('toggle-menu');

  const isMenuVisible = menu.classList.contains('show-menu');

  if (isMenuVisible) 
  {
    menu.classList.remove('show-menu');
  }
  else
  {
    menu.classList.add('show-menu');

    toggleIcon.classList.toggle('rotate');
  }
}

